# remove_fields & add field link not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Hey I´m following the Railscast #196,197 from Ryan Bates (http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) for nested forms, but it didn´t work.

my model:

```
    class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :abstract, :status, :titel, :user_tokens, :chapters_attributes,  :user_ids

      has_and_belongs_to_many :users
      attr_reader :user_tokens

      has_many :chapters, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true, :order => 'slot'

      validates :titel, :presence => true

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :chapters, :allow_destroy => true

      after_initialize :init
      def init
        self.status = false if self.status?
      end

      def user_tokens=(ids)
        self.user_ids = ids.split(",")
      end
    end
```

the partial _chapter_fields.erb :

```
        <div class="fields">
            <%= f.label :chapter_title, "Chapter Title" %>
            <%= f.text_field :chapter_title %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
            <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
        </div>
```

the _form :

```
        <p><%= f.label :chapters, "Chapters:" %></p>

        <%= f.fields_for :chapters do |builder| %>
            <%= render "chapter_fields", :f => builder %>
        <% end %>
        <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add chapter", f, :chapters , [] %></p>
```

the application_helper.rb :

```
       module ApplicationHelper

         def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
           f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
         end

         def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, attributes)
           if(attributes.size == 0)
             new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
           else
             new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new(attributes)
           end
           fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
             render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
           end
           link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
         end
       end
```

the application.js :

```
      //= require jquery
      //= require jquery_ujs
      //= require_tree .


      function remove_fields(link) {
            $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
            $(link).up(".fields").hide();
      }

      function add_fields(link, association, content) {
          var new_id = new Date().getTime();
          var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
          $(link).up().insert({
          before: content.replace(regexp, new_id)
        });
      }
```

Everything is exactly like the tutorial... what am I missing???

I found the same Question but without answer...
[same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516302/remove-fields-add-field-link-not-working-on-nested-form-in-rails-3-0-9)

thats my firebug output:

```
   <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/books/6">Destroy</a>
```

Comment: I just recognized that link_to for delete doesn´t work and while my research I recognized also that it has something to do with not working JS. Might it be that this is the reason for this problem too?