# Adding a basic nested field dynamically without the "link_to_function" deprecated in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For a month I have been struggling to get the hang of nested forms. It has been difficult because the examples are very complicated and include code that is now deprecated. I have it all worked out except adding the fields dynamically.  I am hoping to see the minimum code necessary for the most basic application which I have built here - a parent called 'parent' with one nested child association called 'child'.

Here is the approach I have seen for more complicated examples,

It would involve a function to generate the link in the parents/_form.html.erb

```
 <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Child", f, :children %></p>
```

In the application helper, this code defines the method:

```
# Method for Adding fields

  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end
```

My four problems with it are:
1. It still contains the link_to_function;
2. it is written to handle adding links for any association (not just the one child);
3. It is complicated difficult to follow for someone new to rails, and;
4. I don't know if there are parts that won't work in rails 4.

I tried to rewrite it so that it worked just for the child field, but I couldn't get far enough. If someone could show me what that looked like it would be awesome because I might have a chance at understanding it.

The next piece of code goes into the application.js (or somewhere in the tree).

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
 var new_id = new Date().getTime();
 var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
 $(link).up().insert({
 before: content.replace(regexp, new_id)
 });
}
```

It can probably be called using JQuery instead of the link_to_function. I see that we are trying to create a unique id for object. I don't think the regexp is needed if it is only working on the child_fields. I'm not sure what the "g" is for. Can someone refactor this so it is the minimum required for this simple example?

For clarity I will include the rest of the application.
There is a parent scaffold and a child model. The code displayed should be quite familiar and works fine. It simply lacks the code to dynamically add additional children.  To see an answer to this specific question would be an immense help. Thank you.

I will add some extraneous narration in italics for the benefit those still struggling to understand the workings of the nested form itself.

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131120185052) do

  create_table "children", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "child_name"
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "children", ["parent_id"], name: "index_children_on_parent_id"

  create_table "parents", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "parent_name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

*This schema was created by running 3 commands in the terminal:*
1. rails generate scaffold parent parent_name
2. rails generate model child child_name parent:references
3. rake db:migrate

**parent.rb**

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :children, dependent: :destroy  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, reject_if: proc { |a| a[:child_name].blank?}, allow_destroy: true  
end
```

*The dependent::destroy causes the child to be removed from
the database when the parent is deleted.*
*You can see the difference by checking Parent.all
and Child.all in the rails console.*
*The accepts-nested-attributes-for allows the child to be saved by the parent controller.*
*The proc is similar, it won't create an empty child
in the data base if the parent is created by itself.*
*The allow-destroy lets you delete a child but not the parent.*

**child.rb**

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent  
end
```

*This was automatically added by rails.*

**parents_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @parent = Parent.new
  child = @parent.children.build
end

def parent_params
  params.require(:parent).permit(:parent_name, children_attributes: [:id, :child_name, :parent_id, :_destroy] )
end
```

*A seprate children controller is not needed.*
*The @parent.children.build ensures that the children are associated with the specific parent.*
*The children-attributes: lists the attributes that are allowed to be saved to the child including its own :id and the associated :parent-id.*
*If you forget to add the destroy attribute, you won't be able to delete children on their own.*

**routes.rb**

```
BasicNestedForm::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :parents
  root 'parents#index'
end
```

*Because the children are nested restful routes aren't needed for the actions we are taking so far. The root was set for convenience.*

**parents/_form.html.erb**

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :parent_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :parent_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="fields_for_children">
    <%= f.fields_for :children  do |child_form| %>
     <%= render 'child_fields', f: child_form %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

*The nested elements use fields-for instead of the parents form-for.*
*The f: child-form passes the form builder into the child-fields partial*

I am removing the child just using jQuery - I left the code in the child_fields partial because it didn't seem to function when I stuck it in it's own .js file in the asset tree.

**parents/_child_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="removable">
  <%= f.label :child_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :child_name %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "Remove Child", "#", class: "remover_link"  %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('document').ready( function() {
    $('.remover_link').click(function(event){
      $(this).prev("input[type=hidden").val("1");
      $(this).closest('.removable').hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

*The link-to doesn't have a destination but it supplies the class for jQuery to select.*
*The click function is sneaky; although it sets the hidden destroy attribute to true by giving it a value of 1, it only makes the child element seem to disappear by hiding it from view.*
*The child isn't actually deleted until the update button on the form is clicked.*

**Reiterating the question: What minimum code is needed to add more child elements dynamically without using the "link_to_function"?**

Answer (score 0):

So you're just trying to add fields to a nested form? Check out this railscast to add 'child' fields dynamically to a form: http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms

Essentially you just do a "link_to_add_fields" which you can define in your application helper and then help out with a few lines of javascript. If you don't want to pay for the railscast (it's a pro episode), you can find essentially the same code here: [remove_fields & add field link not working on nested form in rails 3.0.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516302/remove-fields-add-field-link-not-working-on-nested-form-in-rails-3-0-9)

Comment: Hey, sincere thanks for the direction. I do have a pro account at railscasts but at this point they are so far beyond me I just laugh.

Comment: no probs. try following the railscast using the application_helper and then if you're still having trouble let me know! it's essentially just about making sure your params match up in the right positions (e.g. making sure you have f where f should be, calling your association :children where the association param should be, etc)

Comment: Thanks. I had watched this cast before and I went through it again but I was pretty much blown away, especially when I saw the line:   "<%= render "products/fields/#{field.field_type}", field: field, f: builder %>" I did get a method working where I used jquery to add the entire div of html for the input field. It would work if I came up with a way to increment the id. I also tried another brute force strategy of loading the partial but the f wasn't recognized. Do you think you could refactor the code I added at the beginning of the question to make it work for the simple case?

Comment: I'm a bit lost - can you explain again what exactly isn't working for you? If you're unable to get the fields to render where you want them to, pass a css selector into link_to_add_fields(), link_to_function(), and add_fields () and be sure to append the field to that. What id are you trying to increment and why? Also, I don't think you need to build the children in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is posibo with cocoon gem, it automatically recognizes the association and jquery does its magic
Eg instead of using the helper "link_to_add_fields", with cocoon gem you just have to call one function i.e. link_to_add_association.
And thts it. I hope this helps out someone.